# How to create a scoreboard for Pong game in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a working Pong game which keeps track of the score. But when I export it (build) to HTML5 or Windows the scoreboard fails to work. It even stops working in the Unity editor.

My question is does anyone know a simple working scoreboard I can use.

This is the code I used to keep score.

```
public class Count_Score : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text Scoreboard;
public GameObject ball;

private int Bat_1_Score = 0;
private int Bat_2_Score = 0;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    ball = GameObject.Find("Ball");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (ball.transform.position.x >= 13f)
    {
        Bat_1_Score++;
    }
    if (ball.transform.position.x <= -13f)
    {
        Bat_2_Score++;
    }

    Scoreboard.text = Bat_1_Score.ToString() + " - " + Bat_2_Score.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: Is this script added as a component to a game-object in the world? If so, is the inspector-values set properly? You can include a screenshot of the component, as well as the scene hierarchy

Comment: If it stops working in the unity editor there should be errors, or ability to debug whats going on

Comment: Exported (HTML or .exe) will probably be fullscreen or at least different resolution. So comparing positions against fixed values seems very wrong. Attatch a collider, mark it as "is trigger" and then use `OnTriggerEnter` function to increase your score.

Comment: Yes, the script is added as a component to a gameobject. Here's an image: https://ibb.co/xX61v7V And there are no errors or bugs but to fix it I had to delete the GameManager object and  create a new one and reattach the Countscore script and scoreboard and ball objects to it.

Comment: KYL3R - I'm new to unity. Can you elaborate on how the code would look like with OnTriggerEnter?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use `OnCollisionEnter2D`. This is a lot better than using position.

[OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) can be used to check to see if one object has collided with another.

If you have two GameObjects (a right wall and a left wall) you can check to see if the ball has collided with them.

Eg:

```
// Attached to the left wall GameObject
private void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{
    Bat_2_Score++;
}
```

You could then update your score text however you want. I would recommend you do this in an Update() method.

Make sure your ball and wall objects have a collider attached to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll give it a try. But the compiler gives several errors : The name 'OnCollisionEnter' does not exist in the current context,   'Collision' is a type, which is not valid in the given context and The name 'collision' does not exist in the current context 
 Maybe I'm missing some code? I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: @b8360962I'm very sorry - I missed out some simple stuff while writing that code! I've edited it now.

Comment: After exporting it for the 30th time, the scoreboard magically works. I essentially did not change anything. Thanks everyone for your input. I'm sure it's just a software glitch